# Separate and neat display of Equation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have a simple equation for Delta as shown below:

[image: Delta]

Can MATLAB return the parametric form of Delta as below?

[image: Delta separate form]

Comment: This is not off-topic and is related to programming. Matlab supports symbolic math.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For symbolic expressions, you can use the `collect` function.

```
>> collect(delta,[s1,s2,s3])

ans =

s1/k + s2/k + (-1/k)*s3
```